# regular expression new line is not mtaching

Tags: regex

I want to match with a pattern all anchor tags containing "goto" in the href attribute.I am using php. I want to match links like:

```
<a  href='http://www.mysite.com/goto/profile'>links </a>
```

I have written a regex like:

```
<a.*(href).*(goto).*<\/a>
```

It is working for all links like above. But if there is a new line in the anchor tag then it does not match. E.g:

```
 <a  href='http://www.mysite.com/goto/profile'>
links </a>
```

It does not match because of the new line. I need a regular expression to match links with and without new lines.

Comment: What language/tool/whatever are you using for “executing” your regex?

Comment: Generally [using regexes to parse HTML is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). In your specific case, though, you can probably get away with it using the multiline flag.

Comment: Maybe just use a parser instead of processing with regexp.  It can be easier.  You don't mention what platform you are on or one could be suggested

Comment: Please see edited question again.I am using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
<a.*(href).*(goto).*([\n]*.*)*<\/a>
```

For parsing html it is advisable to use a html parser rather than regex. Depending on the language there are various html parsers available. eg: in python you have beautifulsoup.

Comment: Using the parser is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the "dot all" modifier `/s`.

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **/s (PCRE_DOTALL)**
>   If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Hence, `/.*/` will create new matches per line while `/.*/s` will match all lines.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/hA3sQ1)

[DEMO (without DOTALL)](http://regex101.com/r/dE3aW8)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a(.|\n)*(href).*(goto)(.|\n)*<\/a>` to allow multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

If u want the multiple lines only in the anchor tag, as you described it, do it like that:

```
<a.*(href).*(goto).*(>)(.|\n)*<\/a>
```

A Smart Testing tool for PHP can be found here: [PHP LIVE REGEX TESTER](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)